# DXTreeview with AngularJS will not allow branches to be expanded

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5, devextreme

I have an MVC5 project with the following Index.aspx
When I run the project in VS2013 I can only see the top branches of the tree, with no apparent way to expand them.

[image: as shown here]

Resharper indicates that my references are OK.

I am new to HTML5 programming and Angular. How do I go about trouble shooting this problem?

Index.aspx is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/dx.common.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/dx.light.css"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.globalize/globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/dx.webappjs.js"></script>
    <script src="/MyJS/script_Angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div  ng-controller="demoController">
<div dx-tree-view="{
    dataSource: treeViewData,
    dataStructure: 'plain'
}">
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and script_Angular is

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dx']);
myApp.controller("demoController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.treeViewData = dataArray;
});

var dataArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Animals",
        items: [
            {
                id: 2,
                text: "Cat",
                items: [
                    { id: 5, text: "Abyssinian" },
                    { id: 6, text: "Aegean cat" },
                    { id: 7, text: "Australian Mist" }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                text: "Dog",
                items: [
                    { id: 8, text: "Affenpinscher" },
                    { id: 9, text: "Afghan Hound" },
                    { id: 10, text: "Airedale Terrier" },
                    { id: 11, text: "Akita Inu" }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                text: "Cow"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        parentId: 0,
        text: "Birds",
        items: [
            { id: 13, text: "Akekee" },
            { id: 14, text: "Arizona Woodpecker" },
            { id: 15, text: "Black-chinned Sparrow" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set option

`dataStructure: 'plain'`

as it is [hierarchical](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/navigation-tree_view-hierarchical_data_structure) in your case

Removing dataStructure option should help

Docs are [here](http://jsserver.corp.devexpress.com:8080/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Configuration/?version=15_1#dataStructure)